# Why is "if (i++ && (i == 1))" false where i is an int holding the value 1?

Tags: c, if-statement, logical-operators

```
{
    int i = 1;
    if (i++ && (i == 1))
        printf("Yes\n");
    else
        printf("No\n");
}
```

As per my understanding, in the `if` condition, first the expression (`i==1`) will be evaluated which should return `1`, and then it is logically anded with `1` which is the value of `i`, so the expression should return `1 && 1 == 1`, but the `else` part is executed.

Can someone please explain why the `else` part is executed?

Comment: Not the issue, but you don't need parentheses around `i == 1`.

Comment: It looks like you might be expecting `i == 1` to be evaluated first because you have some expectation that things in parentheses happen first. They don't; parentheses have nothing to do with evaluation order. They only control argument grouping.

Comment: @Pete Becker: Yes you do, in order to make your intent clear to the reader - and to make sure that the compiler does what you really intended it to do.  Not that it really applies in this case: if that snippit is in actual production code, the author should never work again.

Comment: A little related: You can also use a single ampersand (`&`). it will check the first argument, and if it is `false` (or _false-ly_), it will skip the checking the next arguments, since the whole argument is already `false`.

Comment: @Gideon Using `&` rather than `&&` does not force the left side of the operand to evaluate first: the sequence point does not exist with `&` between the two sides.  With `&`, the right side could evaluate first.  OP is correct in asking about `&&`.  With `&` it is undefined behavior.  See [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31364104/2410359)

Comment: Another case of why you should never ever use `++` in any other way than alone, and purely for the incrementation effect. This operator is confusing for far too many people. More broadly, that's also why it's best to avoid any kind of side effect while evaluating a condition.

Comment: Why do C programmers have a propensity to write code that needs to be carefully dissected before it can be understood?  :-)

Comment: @EricJ. In real life, most people don't write code like this most of the time (99.9% of people, 99.99% of the time).  There isn't any point to it as 'production code'.  There is some point to it as a training exercise, to make people think about the operators and how they behave, and maybe help them understand undefined behaviour (though I have reservations about the attempts we normally see here on SO).

Answer (score 92):

No.  In C, there's a [sequence point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) between the evaluation of the LHS of the `&&` operator and the evaluation of the RHS, and the increment must take place and be completed before the RHS is evaluated.  So, the `i++` (equivalent to `i++ != 0`) is executed and the increment is completed (and the expression evaluates to true), so by the time the RHS is evaluated, `i == 2` and hence the overall expression is false and you get 'No' printed.  If the LHS of the `&&` operator evaluated to false (0), the RHS would not be evaluated because of the 'short-circuit' property of the `&&` operator.

Only a few operators have the property of having a sequence point between the evaluation of the LHS and RHS: `&&`, `||`, and `,` (as an operator, not as a separator in an argument list) — and there's `? :` too, which isn't a binary operator but which has a sequence point after the condition is evaluated and before either the expression after the `?` or the expression after the `:` is evaluated (of which one or the other, but not both, is always evaluated).

The `&&` and `||` operators are the only operators with the 'short-circuit' property.  The RHS of `&&` is only evaluated if the LHS evaluates to true; the RHS of `||` is only evaluated if the LHS evaluates to false.

---

#### Clarification on Sequence Points

[Iwillnotexist Idonotexist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2809095/iwillnotexist-idonotexist) correctly [asserted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31364078/why-is-if-i-i-1-false-where-i-is-an-int-holding-the-value-1/31364104#comment50716306_31364104):

> The C11 standard hasn't done away with sequence points, only the C++11 standard did.

C++11 (ISO/IEC 14882:2011) says:

> **1.9 Program execution**
>
> ¶13 *Sequenced before* is an asymmetric, transitive, pair-wise relation between evaluations executed by a single
>   thread (1.10), which induces a partial order among those evaluations. Given any two evaluations *A* and *B*, if
>   *A* is sequenced before *B*, then the execution of *A* shall precede the execution of *B*. If *A* is not sequenced before
>   *B* and *B* is not sequenced before *A*, then *A* and *B* are *unsequenced*. [*Note:* The execution of unsequenced
>   evaluations can overlap. —*end note*] Evaluations *A* and *B* are *indeterminately sequenced* when either *A*
>   is sequenced before *B* or *B* is sequenced before *A*, but it is unspecified which. [*Note:* Indeterminately
>   sequenced evaluations cannot overlap, but either could be executed first. —*end note*]

The term 'sequence point' does not appear in C++11 at all (the only near match is 'sequence pointer').

C11 (ISO/IEC 9899:2011) says:

> 5.1.2.3 Program execution
>
> ¶3 *Sequenced before* is an asymmetric, transitive, pair-wise relation between evaluations
>   executed by a single thread, which induces a partial order among those evaluations.
>   Given any two evaluations *A* and *B*, if *A* is sequenced before *B*, then the execution of *A*
>   shall precede the execution of *B*. (Conversely, if *A* is sequenced before *B*, then *B* is
>   *sequenced after* *A*.) If *A* is not sequenced before or after *B*, then *A* and *B* are
>   *unsequenced*. Evaluations *A* and *B* are *indeterminately sequenced* when *A* is sequenced
>   either before or after *B*, but it is unspecified which.<sup>13)</sup> The presence of a *sequence point*
>   between the evaluation of expressions *A* and *B* implies that every value computation and
>   side effect associated with *A* is sequenced before every value computation and side effect
>   associated with *B*. (A summary of the sequence points is given in annex C.)
>
> <sup>13)</sup> The executions of unsequenced evaluations can interleave. Indeterminately sequenced evaluations
>   cannot interleave, but can be executed in any order.

So, C11 does retain sequence points, but adds the 'sequenced before' and related terms using essentially the same terminology as C++11.

Comment: Perfect. `if ((i == 1) && i++ )` would have printed `Yes`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks for qualifying with _what used to be called a sequence point_.  I didn't realize the terminology had been changed and extended in C++11 (c.f. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point)).

Comment: @Equality7-2521: The 'sequenced before', 'sequenced after', 'indeterminately sequenced' and 'unsequenced' terminology also applies to C11.  The new terminology was introduced, in part, because of the addition of threading support in both standards, I believe.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: (side note) If I remember correctly sequence point for `?:` is guaranteed only once, that is immediately after evaluation of its first operand (i.e. condition) and nothing more.

Comment: As a bit more info, these also used to be called _short-cutting operators_ in that they cut-short the expression as soon as the overall result is known (for && if first is false, whole will be false so it cut shorts).  In VB, the 'And' operator did _not_ shortcut and caused all sorts of issues for C devs, so they added 'AndAlso' and 'OrElse'.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski; Yes you are right. In `x++ ? x-- : x`,  modification to `x` by the expression `x++` is sequenced before the evaluation of any of `x--` or `x`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The C11 standard hasn't done away with sequence points, only the C++11 standard did (for whatever reason). §6.5.13p4: _Unlike the bitwise binary `&` operator, the `&&` operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; if the second operand is evaluated, there is a **sequence point** between the evaluations of the first and second operands. If the first operand compares equal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated._ (emphasis added)

Answer (score 41):

**Here, a simple explanation**

[image]

and that's why this condition becomes 'false'

Comment: Nothing new added apart from existing answers,hence a downvote!

Comment: @shekharsuman No, I myself found this answer the clearest, unless of course you want to undersand this concept in a formal way.

Comment: Clean and simple, but it does not explain why the expression in the parenthesis did not get executed first.

Comment: This states what happens but doesn't explain why. For example, the code `if (i++ & (i == 1)) [...]` (note single ampersand) would have different results but your answer doesn't mention any of the concepts that would help somebody work out why.

Comment: Actually, I think it is simple enough. It explains the behaviour through the diagram. It's perfectly fine to me.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 It does, as && operator has left to right precedence so it won't bother evaluating what is on its RHS before totally completing LHS.

Comment: @Prashant It does not. Where in the answer did you see it explaining that? OP knew what happened: `i` became 2 which means the expression on the left was executed first. The question isn’t what happened, but rather *why* it happened.

Answer (score 29):

When `&&` is used in an expression, its arguments are guaranteed to be **evaluated from left to right**. So `i` will have the value of `2` when `(i==1)` is evaluated. Therefore, the expression is false, and the `else` part will be executed.

However, note for completeness that if the left argument evaluates to false or 0, then the right argument is not evaluated at all.

Comment: Not a very clear formulation. What does "guaranteed to be evaluated from left to right" mean if the second argument is not even guaranteed to be evaluated at all? (It means that if the second argument is evaluated at all, then this is done after the evaluation of the first argument, including any of its side effects, is completed; so that is what you should have said.)

Comment: In this context the guarantee means the parentheses won't be evaluated first, pretty clear to me. +1 for @MichaelL's simple explanation, although the discussion of sequence points is central to the understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I think 1&&1=1 and 1&&0=0 is clear to you.
Michael L 's answer seems good to me.But still I will try to elaborate a little bit.
Here is link which provides operator precedence list:

http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm

If you visit the this link and refer that table then you will come to know that && has left to right associativity.So first i will become 2 AFTER left part(Sruit tried to show this using diagram);then for right part i==1 checking is done.We can check this by writing the code like the one given below:

This code explains that i=2 when execution flow reaches i==1 part.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    
    int i = 1;
    if (i++ && (printf("%d\n",i)))
        printf("Yes\n");
    else
        printf("No\n");
    return 0;
}
```

So the output is:

> 2
>
> Yes

So 2==1 comes out to be false and ultimately the answer gives surprising feel!!!
Right hand side bracket gives 0 and left side 1 so 1&&0=0.
I think this is fair enough to understand.

Comment: Even though I somewhat find your last idea of printing the value of _i_ in the last code example interesting, IMO the code (especially without comments) can't be used as explanation. Also I didn't find any purpose for the _1&2 gives o;_ example since that isn't even close to what happens in question. And still, when you reference some source, please include the essential parts of it in your post. This is done for your answer to keep its value even though the link dies.

Answer (score 0):

You are confused because in loop statement **i++** is used for post increment.
e.g.

```
for (i=0;i<1;i++)
```

In the above loop program, `i` will first get initial value and check condition. The `if` condition is true, so it increments **i** and evaluates **i** to old value for the body of loop but outside the loop body it has new value **1**.

In your question you are using `if` and scope of old value of `i` will end when it encounters logically operator it automatically get new value and increment to **2** so the condition returns false.